# Google AppEngine + Local JUnit Tests + Jersey framework + Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, jersey, embedded-jetty

I use Google Appengine for Java (GAE/J).
On top, I use the Jersey REST-framework.

Now i want to run local JUnit tests. The test

- sets up the local GAE development environment ( http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html ),
- launches an embedded Jetty server,
- and then fires requests to the server via HTTP and checks responses.

Unfortunately, the Jersey/Jetty combo spawns new threads. GAE expects only one thread to run.
In the end, I end up having either no datstore inside the Jersey-resources or multiple, having different datastore.

As a workaround I initialise the GAE local env only once, put it in a static variable and inside the GAE resource I add many checks (This threads has no dev env? Re-use the static one). And *these* checks should of course only run inside JUnit tests.. (which I asked before: "How can I find out if code is running inside a JUnit test or not?" - I'm not allowed to post the link directly here :-|)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe use a System property...
When it's a Junit run set a Java system property via a JVM arg which you can then test for something like this:

- pass in a JVM arg via run config parms when testing (in IDE etc maybe) like this:  `-DRunningTestsOnly=true`
- in code: `if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("RunningTestsOnly")))`

I've done similar to this in JUnit tests before, using assume to ignore tests I think take too long to run on my underpowered dev PC...

- pass in JVM arg: `-DexecuteQuickRunningTestsOnly=true`
- To ignore a slow running test method if property set I put at the top of the method : `assumeThat(System.getProperty("executeQuickRunningTestsOnly", "false"), is("false"));`

Comment: Also consider using environment variables, accessed in code via for example `String runLevel = System.getenv("RUN_LEVEL");`. That *language independent* mechanism is popular for allowing your program to have different configuration parameters in different environments (dev, test, integration, CI, production, etc)

Comment: Also, if you're using Gradle, it auto-sets the property `org.gradle.test.worker` when testing, [see the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_execution)

Comment: In case others run into it, I've not dug deeply, but the `org.gradle.test.worker` property seemed to be present when running directly from gradle, but missing when running in IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:
You could create an Exception and then iterate over the exception's stack trace to see if thers's a class from the junit package in there.