# Test case for Android SQLite Connection checking

Tags: android, testcase

I am new in android test cases. i want to write test case for  SQLite database. How can i write test cases and how to check that one. please any one help me. Is is possible or not?

In android using Robotium we can test the application, but here can check table created into sqlite, and insert data into database like this type mean how will write testcase for android database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know the app clearly to write test cases. No one can help you to write test case without knowing the system. See [this](http://inderpsingh.blogspot.in/2011_02_01_archive.html) for an example test case.  You can use [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to automate your android test case execution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very well put and I can justify the downvote you received.

However if I get you correctly you deal with one big issue in the Android testing: you will not be able to mock the database (as well as the private file storage). The `InstrumentationTestCase` allow you to use special `Context` and use the test project's `asset` and `raw` folders, but does not define private file storage and database.

Some time ago I was fighting with this issue and could not solve it. Finally I turned out to be using the real application's database and making sure all the test data is eventually deleted. Ugly unstable and hard to maintain, but there was no other option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096378/testing-database-on-android-providertestcase2-or-renamingdelegatingcontext

Comment: What @selva is getting at is to use `RenamingDelegatingContext` which allows for test files & test databases as per that linked question.