# Testing SQLiteOpenHelper subclass with JUnit

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I am writing JUnit tests for my Android app. I have read through the Android developer resources (testing fundamentals, Spinner example test, etc.). Now I want to test my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass independently of the Activities which use it. My idea is to extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity>`. Is it okay to simply use `Activity` as the generic parameter or do I need a subclass? Also, am I headed in the right direction here, or is there a better way to test my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass?

Comment: A normal `AndroidTestCase` should be sufficient. For testing purposes, using a `ContextWrapper` that mocks the `SQLiteDatabase` created by the database helper might be useful (which can be done by overriding `Context#openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, CursorFactory)`)

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Jens Can you provide some more details as an answer? In particular, I'm unclear about overriding `Context#openOrCreateDatabase()`. Do you mean creating a mock `Context` subclass which I pass to the `ContextWrapper`?

Comment: Creating a subclass of ContextWrapper & override openOrCreateDatabase in that should work for you.

Comment: @Jens Just to clarify, why do you suggest subclassing `ContextWrapper` rather than `Context`? What is the difference?

Comment: Subclassing `Context` would mean you'd have to track down all methods used in `Context` by the `SQLiteOpenHelper` - and then call through to the wrapped `Context` returned by your test case - or return suitable mock values for each and every one - i.e. tedious and pointless busy-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to exactly this problem, and found this link as well as another interesting related question here:

- [Android JUnit test for SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499554/android-junit-test-for-sqliteopenhelper)

The [accepted answer by @Pietro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556184/383414) shows some simple code, using a basic `AndroidTestCase`, which will help directly to answer the question.

```
public class DatabaseTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    private MyDatabase db;

    public void setUp(){
        RenamingDelegatingContext context 
        = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");
        db = new MyDatabase(context);
    }

    public void testAddEntry(){
        // Here I have my new database which is not connected to the standard database of the App
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        db.close(); 
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

I was happy at how simple it looks. In my case I'm new to Android testing, so even the simple stuff seems difficult at the moment.

---

But the **interesting part** which is key, is using the [`RenamingDelegatingContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/RenamingDelegatingContext.html) class as your "context" instead of just using a normal context. This seems to build on the comments made by @Jens.

This class wraps a given context and delegates most operations to that context. The useful part is that it `performs database and file operations with a renamed database/file name` ([see documentation online](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/RenamingDelegatingContext.html)).

This allows your TEST code to use an actual different instance of the database to your PRODUCTION code - at least in my case this is going to be useful.

---

Here is another related post where the accepted answer says pretty much the same thing:

- [Testing database on Android: ProviderTestCase2 or RenamingDelegatingContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096378/testing-database-on-android-providertestcase2-or-renamingdelegatingcontext)

Some useful tips in there about using `ContentProvider` instead (but that's a different issue for another day).

Comment: Thank you for the answer to my old question. This is something I am still struggling with. Since asking this question, I have seen the questions that you linked, but I was looking for tests for a ContentProvider. Thank you for relating the same techniques back to testing a SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Sure thing, I find that collecting together different aspects of an issue is very helpful when I'm trying to learn a new approach to something. Also cleans up the site a bit to link the questions together. Hopefully some future readers will find this useful.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I am actually stuck at the part where I need to create the tables. Because surely you'll have to trigger table creation in ur testcase as well? The Name "MyDatabase" is a tad deceiving, because new MyDatabase(context) creates a new SQliteHelper, and not the associated tables - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

following link talk about testing in android:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

may be you have already seen it just posting it in case you have missed going through it.. it is a very good resource to learn about junit in android...

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have mentioned in my post that I have read through the Android testing resources. I am looking for information specific to testing a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0):

For testing with Android Studio,

You should use `MockContext` instead of `RenamingDelegatingContext`.

If you use `RenamingDelegatingContext`, You would get context as null.
For AndroidTestCase, `getContext()` would return null. And for InstrumentationTestCase, `getInstrumentation().getContext()` would return null.

For further information, see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29063736/1020456