# Mocking a database with RenamingDelegatingContext

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am trying to figure out how to use `RenamingDelegatingContext` to mock a database for testing purposes. The tutorials I have found about this class are great but don't quite answer my questions.

- [dtmilano](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-testing-mock-contexts.html) discusses mocking a file with `RenamingDelegatingContext`.
- [jayway](http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/10/using-renamingdelegatingcontext-to-mock-contentresolver-in-android/) gives a tutorial about mocking a `ContentResolver`, but only focus on `openInputStream()` rather than `query()` and the other database-like operations

As far as I can tell, there isn't a tutorial about mocking databases. If I am missing it in my googling, please provide a link. Otherwise, this would be an excellent home for such a tutorial.

**Update:**

[Testing database on Android: ProviderTestCase2 or RenamingDelegatingContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096378/testing-database-on-android-providertestcase2-or-renamingdelegatingcontext) is close to what I am trying to do. The difference is that I have already written tests for my `ContentProvider` using `ProviderTestCase2`. Now I am doing some functional testing with `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` subclasses for some activities which use that `ContentProvider`. I need the instrumentation for menu and button clicks. If I create a mock context with

```
RenamingDelegatingContext context =
    new RenamingDelegatingContext(getTargetContext(), TEST_FILE_PREFIX);
```

how and when do I inject it into the instrumentation?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an actual database without mocking it? No mocking service will be able to mimick a database to a sufficient level to guarantee that passing your test means it will actually work in the database. Why not isolate the logic and db access code so you can test the code and use a transaction roll back or a similar mechanism to get a clean DB environment to test?

Comment: @Thihara My app is open source. What if a user wants to run the test suite without disrupting actual "production" data on their device. Currently my tests use the exact same database. My understanding is that `RenamingDelegatingContext` will add a prefix to the database name and thus use a "real" database but a completely different one from the one used by the actual app. I'm just confused about how to set it up to do so.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096378/testing-database-on-android-providertestcase2-or-renamingdelegatingcontext May be it will help.

Comment: @Thihara Yes, I have seen that Q&A as well. I'll take a closer look to see if I can get anything new from it.

Comment: @Thihara Updated my question, if you'll have a look.

Comment: @alfoks No, I still have not found a satisfactory solution.

Comment: You've tried playing with Mockito?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I haven't looked at Mockito yet. It is on my "To Do" list.