# How can I tell if my Android app is being run by the InstrumentationTestRunner?

Tags: android, android-testing

In my app (a gradle-based, Android Studio project), I have a need to create a file with a different name when running under test. For instance, in production I would like to use the name *com.myapp.file* and when running under test, *com.myapp.file.**tests***.

What I wanted to do was do this:

`String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
MyFile file = new MyFile(packageName);`

I was hoping that the *packageName* would automatically be different when running under test  (./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest) vs. normally. I checked my manifest and it shows that my test manifest has a package name ending with **.test**, but it doesn't seem to be passing this through to the app when running.

Is there a way to either:

1) Update my gradle or project files to use a different package name when running tests

-or-

2) Is there a way to programatically tell than my app is running under test?

Comment: So in a test runner you can run setup and teardown methods. Why not establish the file name in those methods and, where ever you use the file name, accept it as a parameter instead of infering it from the package name?

Comment: Yes, this works. This is the solution I'm currently employing. I posted this question in an effort to find an alternative. The reason I want an alternative is that I had to modify the public constructor of my class to accept the file name, which I'd prefer not to do. I would like to hide this implementation detail, if that makes sense.

Comment: I can understand that. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to tell that you are running a test but I am not 100% on that so since that is the question I won't make that an answer. However, I would consider making the file name something you grab from a shared preference file and set the name in the file in your test setup. Instead of accepting it as a parameter, pull the name from the preference.Just make sure the change the name back in teardown

Answer (score 0):

Actually since Android essentially uses JUnit testing with test runners, I think I can safely say that Android does not give you a way to tell definitively that you are running in test mode. I would follow the advice from this SO Answer here: [How can I find out if code is running inside a JUnit test or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341943/how-can-i-find-out-if-code-is-running-inside-a-junit-test-or-not)

I would definately agree that it is bad practice to be running differently but if you just want to save to a different file on testing that doesn't seem too unfair. I would use shared preferences, or a global variable set in the Application class to check if you are running in testing. Since typically it's a bad idea to refer to testing in your production code though, I think just having the file name defined somewhere and changing it in setup and teardown would be the proper approach here.